# Need to update the Docusign callback URL

Tags: c#, soap, docusignapi

We have recently changed the callback URL for Docusign to our application which have resulted in error while signing the documents that were created before the change. Newly created documents are signed in correct fashion using the correct callback URL.

The documents that are affected are the ones that are still in the signing phase and have not completed their signature. We need to update the callback URL of these documents(envelopes) from the Docusign side.

Is there any such API where we can update this URL for a specific set of documents where we have the envelope id?

Note: We use SOAP URLs to call the Docusign API

Answer (score 0):

You can only set the information when creating the envelope. Note that the POST method has the eventNotification section but the PUT method does not. Once it's created - it cannot be updated.